# C++- getting error while try to use template

Tags: templates, c++11

I am new to c++, and reying to use templates.
I have a function which can get some types.

header:

```
template <typname T>
response_t send_sequence_to_device(map<const string_t, T*> msg2device_p,
    vector<response_t>& result_list, ushort num_attempts=SEND_NUM_ATTEMPTS);
```

Source:

```
template <typname T>
response_t send_sequence_to_device( map<const string_t, T*> msg2device_p,
    vector<response_t>& result_list, ushort num_attempts )
{
    bool is_ok_flag = true;
    response_t r;
    raftor1_logs_t* rlogs;
    map<const string_t, T*>::iterator msg_it;
    for( msg_it=msg2device_p.begin(); msg_it!=msg2device_p.end() and is_ok_flag; msg_it++ )
    {
        r = msg_it->second->send(msg_it->first, true, num_attempts);
        result_list.push_back(r);
        is_ok_flag = is_ok_flag and is_ok(r);

        if( not(is_ok_flag) )
        {
            stringstream ss;
            ss << "ALERT: Sequence aborted due to error on message [" << msg_it->first << "] ";
            if( r.erred() )
                ss << "due to communication failure.";
            else
                ss << "with error message [" << r.msg << "].";
            rlogs->alert.begin_record();
            rlogs->alert.write( ss.str() );
            rlogs->alert.end_record();
        }
    }

    if( is_ok_flag )
        r.set_ok("ok.\n");

    return r;
}
```

I get the following error:

> device_manager.cpp|1076|error: need 'typename' before 'std::map, T*>::iterator' because 'std::map, T*>' is a dependent scope

Comment: Assuming the adequate typedefs are visible from this prototype, it looks fine. Please post a complete code snippet that produces this error.

Comment: @Quentin- this is the relevant code in the header. Do you need the code from the Source?

Comment: do you have `template <class T>` in the source?

Comment: @Sarit8 Not necessarily, but enough of your code that we can compile and see the error. The best way to do that is with an online compiler such as [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). If for some reason this isn't possible, you should provide as much information as possible : where exactly the error happens, what all of the involved types are, etc.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x- no, I don't have.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x- I changed the class to typename and adding the tepmlate<typname T*> to the source. Now I got another error (edited the question).

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
map<const string_t, T*>::iterator msg_it;
```

You need this:

```
typename map<const string_t, T*>::iterator msg_it;
```

Comment: I can also read the error:) But why do I need the typename, and why only in the source?

Comment: You need `typename` because the compiler can't know in advance if map<string, T>::iterator is a type or a value.  C++ requires that in such cases the compiler should assume it's a value, unless you explicitly say it's a typename.  And why in this case, well that's because it has the form klass<T>::type, where T is a template argument in the enclosing scope.

Comment: but why I don't have to write is also in the heder file?

Comment: @Sarit8: Because you never had the pattern `klass<T>::type` in the header.  Only `klass<T>` which doesn't need `typename`.

Comment: I guess you mean class<t>::type. I have the same template <typname T> in the header as I have in the source.

Comment: @Sarit8 John is referring to `map<const string_t, T*>::iterator`. The type iterator depends on the template `map<const string_t, T*>`, so it is a dependent type. The error is only generated in a cpp file because the template is instantiated when it is used. When the compiler first sees a template function, it does only very limited checking because it does not know what T is. When you then use the template somewhere, it does the full syntax check and generates the error.